# jQuery load only when refresh

Tags: jquery, forms, refresh, jquery-load

I have designed a microsite that has two pages, one with text and a button to go to the second with a form that has some fields that you can write over them and other that are disabled and you can only write over them if you select one option of one field. The problem is that it works only when you refresh the page. The js code is the following:

```
   function addLoadEvent(fn) {
    var old = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = fn;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            old();
            fn();
        }
    }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
    SLIDER.siguiente();
});

var SLIDER = {
    siguiente : function(){
        var s = document.getElementById('country');
        var country = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
        if(country == 'United States of America'){
        $('.inputText').removeAttr('disabled');
        }else{
        $('.inputText').attr('disabled','disabled');}

    }}
```

Does anybody know how can I load jQuery before??

Comment: If you are going to use jQuery, you can dump most of your Javascript code. Do you have an example of your pages?

Comment: You probably need to use jQuery for it. Look at this http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: and make sure that you load jQuery before you add the code for `.ready()`.